# Use same password to two diffrent ssh auth files

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have two files of SSH that I'm using them in a daily basis. In order to avoid typing the password each time I'm using it, I'm using ssh-agent:

```
init-ssh() {
     eval `ssh-agent -s`
     ssh-add /home/user/.ssh/file1
     ssh-add /home/user/.ssh/file2
}
```

Because those two ssh files are having the *same passphrase*, I'm wondering if it's possible to type the password only 1 time and it will add the two identities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include all the keyfile names on a single command line:

```
ssh-add /home/user/.ssh/file1 /home/user/.ssh/file2
```